# printing integer backwards in assembly for macos x86_64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am trying to print an integer in assembly x86_64 on macOS. I already know there are roughly 3/4 answers but I could not solve my problem.

For now, I would be satisfied to print it backwards.
So, this is the code:

```
section .bss                                                            
  3 number_back                 resb                3                       
  4 number_right                resb                3                       
  5                                                                         
  6 section .text                                                           
  7     global _main                                                        
  8 _main:                                                                  
  9     mov rax, 123                                                        
 10     call _get_backwards                                                 
 11                                                                         
 12     mov rax, 0x2000004                                                  
 13     mov rdi, 1                                                          
 14     mov rsi, number_back                                                
 15     mov rdx, 3                                                          
 16     syscall                                                             
 17                                                                         
 18     mov rax, 0x2000001                                                  
 19     xor rdi, rdi                                                        
 20     syscall                                                             
 21                                                                         
 22 _get_backwards:                                                         
 23     xor rdx, rdx                                                        
 24     mov rcx, 10                                                         
 25     div rcx                                                             
 26     add rdx, 48                                                         
 27     mov [rel number_back], rdx                                          
 28                                                                         
 29 loop:                                                                   
 30     inc number_back                                                     
 31     cmp rax, 0                                                          
 32     jne _get_backwards                                                  
 33     ret
```

### Explanation

1. mov rax, 123    ; move number into rax register
2. call get_backwards procedure
3. division and mult require 2 registers, one for the quotient one for the remainder.Xor the remainder so I get rid of all the garbage
4. mov into rcx, 10 so that I can get the remainder which corresponds to the last digit of the number, 3 in this case
5. divide rax by rcx
6. get the ascii code of the int
7. move the content of the rdx register into the memory address held by the pointer number_back
8. here is the part that causes problems. I’d like to do somthing like number_back[0] = 3, number_back[1] = 2 ... . I thought that increasing the pointer by one would make trick, but I am not correct. I am getting this error

```
error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

9. If rax is 0 exit otherwise loop

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can't increment a label as it is not stored anywhere in memory, just a named alias that will be replaced by the address to the memory you allocated. The way to do it would be to have an extra register (`RBX` is free right now) to store the offset you need to add to your address. An other problem with your code is that you will store a (ten) base representation of your value as word in you backward number, which will exceed your capacity. I guess that you are trying to print your number in the "normal" left to right way. What you should do is to reserve some more space if you want to do it this way (3bytes => 8 characters).

```
section .bss                                                            
 number_back                 resb                8; 8 characters                       
 number_right                resb                3   
section .text
    global _main
    _main:
     mov rax, 123 
     mov rbx, 0                                                       
     call _get_backwards                                                 
                                                                         
     mov rax, 0x2000004                                                  
     mov rdi, 1                                                          
     mov rsi, number_back                                                
     mov rdx, 3                                                          
     syscall                                                             
                                                                         
     mov rax, 0x2000001                                                  
     xor rdi, rdi                                                        
     syscall                                                             
                                                                         
 _get_backwards:                                                         
     xor rdx, rdx                                                        
     mov rcx, 10                                                         
     div rcx                                                             
     add rdx, 48                                                         
     mov [rel number_back + rbx], rdx                                          
                                                                         
 loop:                                                                   
     inc rbx                                                    
     cmp rax, 0                                                          
     jne _get_backwards                                                  
     ret
```

should work (I don't have a nasm compiler on this computer sorry).

Comment: "you can't increment a value that is not in a register." Incorrect. You can increment a byte, word, dword, or qword sized variable in memory. What you cannot do is increment a label's address, as the question suggested with `inc number_back`. Because there is no memory indirect addressing mode in practice your answer is correct; ie, the address or a displacement to the address needs to be in a register at some point.

Comment: Further I believe that `mov [rel number_back + rbx], rdx` doesn't do what you want. To actually use RIP-relative addressing you need `lea some64bitreg, [rel number_back]` then use `[some64bitreg + rbx]` to address the buffer.

Comment: indeed, that was what i meant. Thanks, i'm going to edit the answer to make it more clear

Comment: @ecm is it a bit better now ?

Comment: thank you for the answer I am going to try your solution immediately

Comment: so technically what you are trying to say is that if I save rdx I am saving 64 bits and not just 1 char. Would it be better to use ah instead

Comment: @laenNoCode: The wording at the beginning is better, but you haven't changed the code to work with RIP-relative addressing yet.

Comment: making the edit as soon as i have a more stable internet connection

Comment: @not_here_to_play: After a 64-bit divide `rdx:rax / rcx` you will have the remainder in `rdx`, which will hold a number in the range 0 to 9, inclusive. Because of this limit, the low byte register `dl` will hold the same value as `rdx`. Just use only `dl` in the `mov` so as to store only a byte.

Comment: I have used as you suggested the lea instruction

Comment: Yes I said ah previously. I meant dl sorry. double mistake

Comment: iaen once you edit the answer I am going to accept it. Thanks to you too

Comment: @ecm: You're correct, the only RIP-relative addressing mode is `[RIP + rel32]`, not involving any other registers.  NASM will unfortunately not reject or even warn for `[rel symbol + rbx]`, instead assembling it to `[disp32 + rbx]` with a relocation for the linker to fill in a 32-bit absolute address.  (This of course doesn't work on MacOS; MachO64 doesn't even have a relocation type for that so it fails right at assemble time with `nasm -fmacho64`, vs. at link time on Linux with `-felf64` if you tried to link into a PIE executable.)

Comment: This answer also still has a bug that it's storing 8 bytes every iteration, overlapping by 7.  So it stores past the end of the `resb 8`, into the `resb 3` that follows, and for larger numbers stores past that too.

Comment: If you don't have NASM locally, you can test on Godbolt.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/q4oTfhd1x shows this code failing to assemble with `nasm -f macho64` (I had to use `-F dwarf` because the default `-F stabs` that compiler explorer passes doesn't work with macho.)